Why doesn't git log show reachable ancestors?
With git log --graph --all --oneline I have:
* G (HEAD -> main, origin/main)
...
* F
* E
* D
* C
* B 
| * Z
|/ 
* A

But if the --all flag is omitted, then the graph is:
* G (HEAD -> main, origin/main)
...
* F
* E

My questions are:

A, B, C, D are reachable from main. Why doesn't git log show them?
Z isn't reachable from any ref. Why does git log --all show it?


This is a confusing question. git log --all doesn't show dangling commits which are unreachable from HEAD, it only shows HEAD plus all refs. So the premise of Z being unreachable from any ref seems impossible.

What is the actual output of Z on your screen? Is it just some hash? If yes could you by chance have a branch or tag name which is exactly that hash?

As for your first question- --oneline  doesn't actually show you the true paths so you can't tell for sure. Maybe E is the root commit for main, and D is the top of another unrelated history. Remove --oneline from your first command to confirm. You'll likely see a break in the path.

Say  git log --all --oneline --graph --source to find out how Z got included in the story.

From the other questions you asked recently, I take you still are dealing with pruning secrets from your repo.

If you remove --oneline from your command, git will have a chance to draw | (vertical lines) if a commit is actually the child of the commit below. You have a rewritten history, and I would bet the E is a root commit, with no parent. It happened to have been drawn right after D, but A-D and E-G are not related.

You seem to have references (branches ? Remote branches ? tags ?) to commits in your old history. Delete or rewrite these references, and move forward.

Have you checked the git log docs?

The git book is a very good reference. Git internals will probably bring quite some light on how your repo behaves.

Also: git for-each-ref will list all the references known to your local repo.

@TTT if Z is reachable to a ref, then shouldn't that ref be displayed in the graph as well, right? Z is a regular commit (AFAIK); I can switch to it like any other commit

Add --decorate to get more clues.

Closed. But OP debugged it themselves.

A, B, C, D or Z seems to be reachable from main. Why doesn't git log show them?
It's because the --oneline flag accidentally obfuscates the graph, making them look like being reachable from main, while in fact they aren't. Omitting that flag reveals that there are actually two root commits, E and A, and the disconnection between them.
There is no branch or tag attaching to A, B, C, D or Z. Why does git log --all show them?
It's because there are more refs than branches, tags and HEAD, and I suspect the command only show them by default. To reveal all refs, use git log --all --source. Or you can use git for-each-ref to examine only the commits being attached to a ref:
git for-each-ref --format="%(objectname:short) %(refname)"
G refs/heads/main
D refs/original/refs/heads/main
Z refs/original/refs/tags/Cấutrúc1
C refs/original/refs/tags/Cấutrúc1.1
G refs/remotes/origin/main

To solve the problem, open the file .git/packed-refs and delete all lines containing the refs/original/refs/ string.
Next question: What does refs/original do?
Thanks TTT, matt, LeGEC for helping me investigate the problem.

After reading this answer I want to upvote both the Q and this A, as it is an interesting learning opportunity. But, you could make this an even better answer by attributing the multiple comments that led to this answer, and then actually answer the title question in a more obvious (explicit) way. (e.g. "This is due to "hidden" refs not displayed by git log", or something like that.) Since you authored the question and the answer, it would also be nice if you could mention what created the "hidden" refs, such as filter-branch or whatever you did to rewrite the repo. (Assuming you know...)

I've rewrite it. Is it better?
